# Why doesn't the rust create openssl-sys compile?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, wasm-pack

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `openssl-sys v0.9.72`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\REBERE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo-installamQyFK\release\build\openssl-sys-612700125c292786\build-script-main` (exit code: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rustc-cfg=const_fn
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_MSVC_OPENSSL_NO_VENDOR
  X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_MSVC_OPENSSL_NO_VENDOR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_NO_VENDOR
  OPENSSL_NO_VENDOR unset
  running "perl" "./Configure" "--prefix=C:\\Users\\REBERE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installamQyFK\\release\\build\\openssl-sys-30b5392f9f091eea\\out\\openssl-build\\install" "no-dso" "no-shared" "no-ssl3" "no-unit-test" "no-comp" "no-zlib" "no-zlib-dynamic" "no-md2" "no-rc5" "no-weak-ssl-ciphers" "no-camellia" "no-idea" "no-seed" "no-engine" "no-asm" "VC-WIN64A"

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error { kind: NotFound, message: "program not found" }', C:\Users\reberezinar\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\openssl-src-111.18.0+1.1.1n\src\lib.rs:477:39
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to compile `wasm-pack v0.10.2`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `C:\Users\REBERE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo-installamQyFK`

Caused by:
  build failed
```

hi, once I have tried to run "cargo install wasm-pack" command, ı have faced the error that has been given below.
OS: 64 bit win10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't install cargo wasm-pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68646684/cant-install-cargo-wasm-pack)

Comment: I have the same problem and cant find a solution. --> Found a workaround tho: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71778074/10523949

Answer (score 0):

check if you have *OpenSSL* already installed.