# wasm-pack install problem - failed to run custom build command for `openssl-sys v0.9.74`

Tags: rust, openssl, rust-cargo, wasm-pack

I'm running cargo 1.61.0 on Windows, and I'm trying to install wasm-pack with the following command:

```
cargo install wasm-pack
```

I'm getting the following error though:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `openssl-sys v0.9.74`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo-installYlYKGY\release\build\openssl-sys-d97a6a84756b04f8\build-script-main` (exit code: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rustc-cfg=const_fn
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_MSVC_OPENSSL_NO_VENDOR
  X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_MSVC_OPENSSL_NO_VENDOR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_NO_VENDOR
  OPENSSL_NO_VENDOR unset
  running "perl" "./Configure" "--prefix=C:\\Users\\X\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installYlYKGY\\release\\build\\openssl-sys-69b856177b1e2088\\out\\openssl-build\\install" "--openssldir=SYS$MANAGER:[OPENSSL]" "no-dso" "no-shared" "no-ssl3" "no-unit-test" "no-comp" "no-zlib" "no-zlib-dynamic" "no-md2" "no-rc5" "no-weak-ssl-ciphers" "no-camellia" "no-idea" "no-seed" "no-engine" "no-asm" "VC-WIN64A"

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error { kind: NotFound, message: "program not found" }', C:\Users\X\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\openssl-src-111.21.0+1.1.1p\src\lib.rs:488:39
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to compile `wasm-pack v0.10.3`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo-installYlYKGY`
```

How do I get past this error?

Comment: Their website says to download an installer when using Windows: https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-pack/installer/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68646684/cant-install-cargo-wasm-pack looks related.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't install cargo wasm-pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68646684/cant-install-cargo-wasm-pack)

Comment: Just in case anyone else has the same problem, I wanted to mention that after looking at the error, I tried installing perl so that it compiled. It did compile, but the exe wouldn't run.